# issue with searching for string inside the array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I almost an hour trying to understand what i doing wrong here. The is no output.

The connection is Ok, The array is full of data

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

// Here's the argument from the client.
$domain = $_GET['string'];
$quest=$_GET['quest'];
$event=$_GET['event'];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', '******', '********');
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("vocabulary", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM `0` WHERE event_name = '".$event."' AND quest_id = '".$quest."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$key = array_search($domain, $row);

echo $key;

mysql_close($con);


?>
```

Any ideas??
Thanks

Comment: Major SQL injection vulnerability in this code. Please look into escaping / PDO. More - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+injection

Comment: What do you have in $domain?

Comment: if domain is a url you could be having issues with escaped characters making the results not match

Comment: Domain is a string like "hi my name is"

Comment: Yes but still it have to return false or 0 or something

Comment: if it's false you'll get no output

Answer (score 3):

A few things.

1. You are selecting from the table named `0`. I don't think you should be doing that.
2. Since I doubt the table `0` exists, my guess is that you have an error at `mysql_fecth_array`. Try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the start of your script.
3. `array_search` returns `False` if it doesn't find anything. Try `var_dump($key);` instead.
4. Your code has a [serious security problem](http://bobby-tables.com/). I suggest that you move over to [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) or [MySQLi](http://www.phphaven.com/article.php?id=65).

[image: Bobby Tables!]

Comment: it did while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['**'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['**'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['**'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['**'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['**'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>"; and it's work perfect.. no problem with a table name and connection

Comment: var_dump($key); return bool(false)

Comment: Your have a formatting issue in your comment. Please place `\`` around all code to make it more readable and disable the markup too.

Comment: @IlyaLibin If you're getting `false` from `var_dump` that means that the search returned 0 entries.

Answer (score 0):

i think your issue is that you're not creating an associative array 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

your mysql_fetch_array is returning an array that has values but not keys, and so there is nothing to be stored in $key. try this instead:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)
```

also, obligatory "you should avoid using mysql_ functions entirely, and move to mysqli or PDO because mysql_ has been deprecated"

Comment: ***All arrays have keys***.  Even numeric arrays.  `array_search` works with numeric arrays.  The key returned just happens to be a number, instead of a string.  Also, `mysql_fetch_array` uses `MYSQL_BOTH` by default, so the array has *both* numeric and associative keys.